# AWS API Gateway secure an end-point

Tags: authentication, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless

I have a Lambda function which triggered by API Gateway service, however this API is accessed by front-end application, this application not requiring the users to login or sign up to use it.

However I would like to secure my API to allow only from my front-end application.

After my research I found that I can use custom authorization in API Gateway, this custom authorization will check the authorization header   of the incoming request and validate it.

the question is, can I use Amazon Cognito for something like this(implicit grant type)?
if not what is the thing that the front-end application will send to me to be validated and how can I keep it always changeable, so no one can guess it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the headers, but if they're always the same, someone can send an HTTP request with those headers - from any client - and trick your Lambda into thinking it's coming from your UI.

Even if you generate a unique token every time your UI is loaded and include it in the headers, someone could take that token and send requests from another client as well.

You could build fancy JavaScript tricks to make headers more dynamic, but it would only make it harder to use your API from another client, not impossible.